# How can I chain calls to Application.ThreadException?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.5

In a WinForms application (.NET 4.5.1) if I add multiple handlers to `Application.ThreadException` only the most recently added handler is called. I don't see this explained anywhere in the documentation. In fact it states, *"Attach your event handlers..."* Note the plural on "handlers".

Here is an example that illustrates the behavior:

```
internal class Form1 : Form
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.ThreadException +=
            (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"This is never printed");
        Application.ThreadException +=
            (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine(@"Only this is printed");

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        var button = new Button {Text = @"CRASH!"};
        button.Click += (sender, args) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```

Is there some way to retrieve the existing handler and call it from my own handler? The reason that I ask is that I'm trying to integrate the new MS AppCenter SDK into my application, and it adds a handler to `Application.ThreadException`. I want to add my own handler but still call the AppCenter handler when an exception occurs.

Here is a pseudo-code that illustrates what I want to do:

```
static void Main()
{
    AppCenter.Start("id", typeof(Crashes));
    var handler = GetCurrentThreadExceptionHandler();
    Application.ThreadException += (sender, args) => {
        handler?.Invoke(sender, args);
        Log("Something happened");
        new UnhandledErrorDialog().Show();
    };
}
```

Comment: You should propably not be using the Application handler for anything but logging. As if it being a global with a single value was not bad enough, it is also likely a bad design for exception handling. I have two articles on exception handling that I link often and that should give you some ideas about teh basics: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: The intended way to deal with Exception in Multitasking is to catch them and hand them out with the Result. The task class has a value to store exceptions. The BackgroundWorker deals with catching and exposing the exception (if there was one and you try to access the result, you get the exception rethrown instead).

Comment: [public static event ThreadExceptionEventHandler ThreadException](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,973)

Comment: @Jimi, do you think it's a bug? `current.threadExceptionHandler = value` vs expected `current.threadExceptionHandler += value` ?

Comment: @noseratio This one should only be subscribed to before `Application.Run`. It's supposed to handle the UI Thread exceptions. There's `UnhandledException` for other threads.

Comment: @Jimi, that's understood but I don't get why they disallow multiple handlers (by using `= value` instead of `+= value`).

Comment: @noseratio This exception can be treated as non-fatal, asking the User to continue (when handled, otherwise [OnThreadException](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Application.cs,3234) will force to quit). So, it seems reasonable to have just one handler for this.

Comment: @Jimi, *seems reasonable to have just one handler for this* ... besides the OP legitimately needs two handlers for this. Feels like a bug to me.

Comment: @noseratio Hmm, AppCenter takes over. Build, tests, deployment, analytics (pre/post deployment)... So, the `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode` behaviour. The OP may want to handle and configure the SDK of [App Center Crashes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/wpf-winforms)

Comment: @Jimi, Unfortunately, right now AppCenter doesn't provide a callback that is called at the time that an exception occurs. I have created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-dotnet/issues/1103) to request this functionality. I will point out again that both the MS documentaion and the API (use of += ) are misleading. I have created [a pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/pull/3108) to have the documentation updated.

Comment: Have you set up your CallBacks before `AppCenter.Start()`?

Comment: @Jimi, There is no callback that occurs at the time an unhandled exception occurs. All the callbacks (as far as I can see) happen at report submission time, which is after the app has already crashed and has been restarted.

Comment: One more comment... `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` apparently doesn't work in the same way as `Application.ThreadException`. I haven't tested it to be sure, but according to [the source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/appdomain.cs,3063) it looks like it supports multiple event handlers.

Comment: Maybe you can work it around using reflection, if desperate :) You'd need add your handler to ThreadContext.threadExceptionHandler